# how do I create an equation in microsoft excel worksheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to create an equation that calculates the amount of native currency using an absolute cell reference formula.  I am doing an assignment and it requires me to find the native currency of $1 equivalent to these 7 different counrtries.  AUSTRIA, BELIZE, CHILE, CZECH REPUBLIC, SWEDEN, THAILAND, AND UKRAINE.  I am having the hardest time trying to figure out how to get the correct answers when I due the work.  Please someone help me out.  Thanks so much...

Comment: show us what you tried, what are your inputs and expected outputs. Your question as stated here is really unclear

Answer (score 0):

An absolute cell reference is referred to by using `$`.

- `$A1` is an absolute reference to column A but the row can change.
- `A$1` is an absolute reference to row 1 while the column can change.
- `$A$1` is an absolute reference to both column A & row 1.

If you want anything more than that, edit your question to let us know what you have tried and exactly which part you are having a problem with.